# Point at different value in JSON blob to put in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some code that works perfect, it pulls the data in the "counts" json field and puts it in an array. Here is that code:

```js
const data = {
  "report": {
    "type": "trended",
    "elements": [{
      "id": "page",
      "name": "Page"
    }],
    "reportSuite": {
      "id": "retail",
      "name": "GlobPROD"
    },
    "period": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 - Fri.  5 Oct. 2018",
    "metrics": [{
      "id": "pageviews"
    }],
    "segments": [{
      "id": "s13bb443734ab6a764639ff37",
      "name": "Information"
    }],
    "data": [{
      "name": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018",
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 10,
      "day": 3,
      "hour": 0,
      "breakdown": [{
        "name": "CATEGORY:>Statement",
        "url": "",
        "counts": ["242"]
      }, {
        "name": "CATEGORY:>Log On",
        "url": "...CheckId.do",
        "counts": ["237"]
      }],
      "breakdownTotal": ["2123"]
    }, {
      "name": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 (Hour 1)",
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 10,
      "day": 3,
      "hour": 1,
      "breakdown": [{
        "name": "CATEGORY:>Statement",
        "url": "",
        "counts": ["152"]
      }, {
        "name": "CATEGORY:>Log On",
        "url": "",
        "counts": ["135"]
      }],
      "breakdownTotal": ["1140"]
    }]
  }
}


const label = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdown.forEach(el => {
    let key = "data";
    if (!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.counts)
  })
  //return r['data'];
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(label);
```

However, I wanted to duplicate this code up, and also pull the "day" field (in the above example, it was 3).

```
const label = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdown.forEach(el => {
     let key = "data";
    if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.day)
  })
  //return r['data'];
  return r;
}, {})

console.log (label);
```

In the above case, I simply changed "counts" to "day" but this gives an error. I think it's because "day" is a level above "counts" in the JSON, so I tried to remove one of the periods before el.day but then it gives me the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.
```

Appreciate it's quite simple but how do I return the day value instead of the counts value.

Comment: Can you give an exact example of your expected output given the data?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yes in this case it would be ["3", "3"] because both entries have day value 3

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that says "undefined, undefined, undefined" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected value is an array, consider using `map`, especially if there will always be a value:

```js
const data = getData()
const days = data.report.data.map(obj => obj.day);
console.log('days:', days);

function getData() {
  return {
    "report": {
      "type": "trended",
      "elements": [{
        "id": "page",
        "name": "Page"
      }],
      "reportSuite": {
        "id": "retail",
        "name": "GlobPROD"
      },
      "period": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 - Fri.  5 Oct. 2018",
      "metrics": [{
        "id": "pageviews"
      }],
      "segments": [{
        "id": "s13bb443734ab6a764639ff37",
        "name": "Information"
      }],
      "data": [{
        "name": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018",
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 3,
        "hour": 0,
        "breakdown": [{
          "name": "CATEGORY:>Statement",
          "url": "",
          "counts": ["242"]
        }, {
          "name": "CATEGORY:>Log On",
          "url": "...CheckId.do",
          "counts": ["237"]
        }],
        "breakdownTotal": ["2123"]
      }, {
        "name": "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 (Hour 1)",
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 3,
        "hour": 1,
        "breakdown": [{
          "name": "CATEGORY:>Statement",
          "url": "",
          "counts": ["152"]
        }, {
          "name": "CATEGORY:>Log On",
          "url": "",
          "counts": ["135"]
        }],
        "breakdownTotal": ["1140"]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the day you don't have to loop through the `breakdown` since the `day` attribute is a direct attribute of the `data.report.data` object, it should be simply :

```
const label = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if( e.hasOwnProperty('day') ) r.push(e.day);

    return r;
}, {})
```

**NOTE:** It will be better to use `.hasOwnProperty()` to check whether the object has the specified property as its own property.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `day` property is a property of the parent object, not of the `breakdown` subproperty, remove the inner loop, and pass in an array as the initial value for the reducer:

```js
const data={"report":{"type":"trended","elements":[{"id":"page","name":"Page"}],"reportSuite":{"id":"retail","name":"GlobPROD"},"period":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 - Fri.  5 Oct. 2018","metrics":[{"id":"pageviews"}],"segments":[{"id":"s13bb443734ab6a764639ff37","name":"Information"}],"data":[{"name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018","year":2018,"month":10,"day":3,"hour":0,"breakdown":[{"name":"CATEGORY:>Statement","url":"","counts":["242"]},{"name":"CATEGORY:>Log On","url":"...CheckId.do","counts":["237"]}],"breakdownTotal":["2123"]},{"name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 (Hour 1)","year":2018,"month":10,"day":3,"hour":1,"breakdown":[{"name":"CATEGORY:>Statement","url":"","counts":["152"]},{"name":"CATEGORY:>Log On","url":"","counts":["135"]}],"breakdownTotal":["1140"]}]}}

const label = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  if (e.day) r.push(e.day);
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(label);
```